# Custom dismiss transition without segue

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

*I have seen various questions/answers on similar topics, but none of them seem very recent.*

If I am just using `pushViewController` to present a view controller with a custom transition, but without a segue, what is the proper way to specify the dismiss transition, and where should I place the animation code?

Push and Initial Transition:

```
let tr = CATransition();
tr.duration = 0.35;
tr.type = kCATransitionPush;
tr.subtype = kCATransitionFromTop;
self.navigationController!.view.layer.addAnimation(tr, forKey: kCATransition);

self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: false);
```

Answer (score 0):

The way you set the push animation is obsolete. 
As of iOS 7, there is a method of `UINavigationControllerDelegate` that allows you to return a custom animator object.

The method signature is `` -navigationController: animationControllerForOperation: fromViewController: toViewController` of `UINavigationControllerDelegate ``

For more information - [check the docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationControllerDelegate_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UINavigationControllerDelegate/navigationController:animationControllerForOperation:fromViewController:toViewController:).